# change style of span by focusing on an input

Tags: css

I want to show word "test" by focusing on text input.
(when text input get focused z-index of text change to 0)
but it didn't work.
(using css.)
my code is just here:

```
.text{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;

    }
    .main{
        background: #ababab;
    }
    .input-textbox input:focus + span {
        z-index: 0;
    }
<div class="main">
    <div class="textbox">
        <input type="text" class="input-textbox">
        <span class="text">test</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question feels a bit rude, because it looks like you didn't put much effort in the text. Please be polite, put some work in grammar, spelling and interpunction (less exclamation marks would be nice). In addition, be more specific about your problem, and tell us what you've tried. All that will help in getting good answers to your questions. Note that you can edit your question at any time to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong selector, change to the following

```
.input-textbox:focus + span {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

here is the [demo](http://jsbin.com/ayokar/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try the selector like this....

```
input.input-textbox:focus + span {
        z-index: 0;
}
```